# Email not showing in all contacts but is in contact attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have a contact that was synced from SF to MC and when I search for him in ALL CONTACTS, he comes up showing his mobile number but no email shows.  When I click his profile and go to attributes and scroll down to contact_salesforce - his email is available.

Any idea why?  I am concerned he may not be able to get emails

Comment: Can you find him in All SUBSCRIBER list?

Comment: If I remember correctly I had the same problem and it turned out that everything worked fine. However, to be sure you can check the _sent data view if he received any mails. That is, if he should have received anything yet.

Comment: YesI can find him in all subscribers but it does not show his email? :(